# Have the Clintons received $153 million in speaker fees?

Tags: united-states, politics, economics

[The Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hill_(newspaper)) reported in an article entitled, [*"Clinton promises to release Wall Street transcripts if opponents do the same"*.](http://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/presidential-races/268560-clinton-promises-to-release-wall-street-transcripts-if)

> Clinton and her husband, former President Bill Clinton, have racked up $153 million in speaker fees since 2001, including from financial firms like Goldman Sachs and UBS.

Is the above claim true?

Comment: [This indicates less](http://www.politico.com/story/2015/05/bill-and-hillary-clinton-made-roughly-25-million-in-speeches-since-2014-118009). It would be interesting to dig up their dataset.

Comment: @JanDoggen: I only skimmed that article, but it seemed to be talking about "since 2014", where the question asks "since 2001".

Answer (score 13):

## True: the Clintons received $153 million in speaker fees.

It seems to be be true. [CNN states](http://www.cnn.com/2016/02/05/politics/hillary-clinton-bill-clinton-paid-speeches/), since 2001,

- **The Clintons** have given 729 speeches; paying an average of $210,795; for a total of $153,699,691.

They break this down to

- **Bill**: 637 speeches; paying an average of $207,255; for a total of $132,021,691.
- **Hillary**: 92 speeches; paying an average of $235,304; for a total of $21,648,000.